# google.maps.MapOptions + JSON: avoid eval()?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am searching for an eval() alternative..

I generate a usal google map, API v3.:

```
    // define options
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856),
      mapTypeId: eval(maptype["map"]),
      panControl: true,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      scaleControl: true
    };

    // create map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_test),mapOptions);
```

This works as it should, but I want to avoid eval(). 
maptype is defined via php, using JSON:

```
echo 'maptype = '.json_encode($options).';';
```

Is there a alternative for eval?

Update:
the full sourcecode:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.7&sensor=false&language=de"></script>
</head>

<body>


<script>
maptype = {"map":"google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE"};</script>

<script>
function Map()
{
var mapOptions = {zoom: 18, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856), mapTypeId: eval(maptype["map"])};

// create map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
}
</script>

<div id="map" style="width:1200px; height:800px"></div>
<script> jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {Map();});</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result: no error, no map, just a grey background.

Comment: Just `mapTypeId: ngggOptions["map"]` should work.

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so it's valid JSON then it's a valid object in JavaScript :)

Comment: You're specifying `v=3.7` in the URL - this version is no longer available; you should probably just remove the `v` parameter

Comment: good to know, but there is no difference

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just remove the `eval()` call around it and it should work, assuming `ngggOptions` is an object and has a key for `map`.

Comment: please post the OUTPUT of the php, not the php itself.

Comment: Ok, for your object, I don't think you need to quote `"google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE"`. Also, what Rocket said, `ngggOptions` is not defined.

Comment: I renamed ngggOptions to maptype, that is defined. The quotes are generated by php using json_encode, it won't work without quotes. Other ideas?